# Removing Accepted Certificate Authorities

Tags: windows, iis, certificate, pki

I need to remove some certificate authorities based on the "Issued To" value so that those certificates are no longer acceptable to access a website.

I'm using the certificate snap-in (Windows 2012 R2) to administer the certificates and am able to select the appropriate entries under Certificates -> Intermediate Certification Authorities -> Certificates, and Delete them. However, once the machine is re-boot the certificate authorities are active again.

I'm am administrator on the machine in question.

Any guidance or thoughts about what is happen would be appreciated.

Thanks -

Comment: The right ways are like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn265983(v%3Dws.11)